# How to select the entire object on edit mode

Tags: objects, edit-mode, selection-tools

I need to have further explanations about how to select everything while I'm on edit mode as in [this tutorial](http://youtu.be/khuHV00QQj4?t=24m40s).

I would like to know how I can select the entire object in edit mode because when I'm on object mode I can select only one part of the object and when I switch to edit mode I can again edit only the part that I have previously selected on object mode. I've tried to do CTRL+G but at the minute 28.11 I saw that it's not the right answer,because she can select each individual piece of the character,but I can't. So,what's the solution ? thanks.

Comment: Press [A] to select every face; And [Ctrl] + [J] to join all selected objects.

Comment: **Please include all information needed in the question, referencing a tutorial means in the future, the question may be incomplete if the link breaks.**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> to join all your objects (they need to be selected). When in *Edit Mode* hit the <kbd>A</kbd> key to select all your points (vertices). You can hit it again to deselect everything. If you want to only select your object, use <kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: I've already tried but I think that's not the solution of the problem. Infact,go to minute 28.11 and tell me how can I select only the head if previously I have joined everything...

Comment: [L] for linked faces/edges.

Comment: You can in edit mode, you are selecting the vertices. I can see that she has joined to object. You can select separate groups of vertices in edit mode by hovering and hitting L

Comment: @Marietto If my post helped you, please hit the check mark button below the voting buttons on the right side of this post. Thanks, it was a pleasure helping you.

Comment: I tried to join objects that are several parts of a map (extracted from Spyro 2 game with SpyroEdit / Genesis tools) but it looks like it breaks UV mapping. Isn't there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join two or more objects together and press <kbd>A</kbd> to select the whole mesh. You can also use <kbd>B</kbd> to select like half of the mesh or do the same for the whole mesh.

Answer (score 0):

You can select multiple objets (=parts) in object mode and enter edit mode for all of them at once.

Then you can naturally press A to select all the geometry. Exit edit mode to change which objets (=parts) are selectable/editable in edit mode.

Be careful of your wording: 'Object' refers to something very specific in blender. Perhaps 'model' is more appropriate.